# Immutable integers

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have read across blogs for immutability of primitive types. They says integers are immutable. Does that means integer variable gets new memory location on every assignment of new values?

I.e.

```
int32 Val= 34;
Val =38;
```

Now both values will be stored on different memory locations or same?

Comment: You've asked four pretty separate questions here - and 2, 3 and 4 have nothing to do with immutability. They have everything to do with `string` being a reference type and `int` being a value type. It would help if you'd ask a single *very specific* question. (Your first question is probably the closest to your title, but it's not really clear what you're asking. If you could show some code it would be much easier to help you.)

Comment: Those questions were stucked after reading different articles. Any guidance for them will be helpful.. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I won't be answering this question, because it's too broad. Stack Overflow questions should be *specific* and *individual*. Asking four broad questions in a single post is not a good idea.

Comment: Just a tip: Don't talk back to Jon Skeet, you'll lose ^^

Comment: The question had already been edited to not be too broad by the time the last close vote was cast. It's answerable now, and not a bad question IMO.

Comment: Hope fully someone will give answer to this question..

Comment: Voted for reopen.

Comment: You've confused variables with values. **Integer variables are mutable** but the *values* are not. There's no way to say "I hereby declare that *the number 12* is now the number 87"; you can only say "I hereby declare that *the variable x* now has the value 87". Make sure you understand the difference.

Comment: If you have LinqPad, you can [download this script](http://share.linqpad.net/xgv2op.linq) and observe what happens to the memory location of an `int` when you modify its value (spoiler - doesn't change).

Comment: @Croecoder, Thanks for the explanation. Picture got cleared..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that means integer variable gets new memory location on every assignment of new values?

Keep in mind that integers are "value types" - meaning that a variable that they are stored in stores the *value* rather then a reference to some memory location.  So when you do:

```
int32 Val= 34;
Val =38;
```

a new *value* is stored in `Val` - so there is only one "memory location" involved, and the *value* at that location is overwritten.

> Now both values will be stored on different memory locations or same?

Well, in that sense the "value" of `34` is not stored *anywhere* anymore.  Does that mean that the number `34` is now `38` anywhere that `34` is used?  By no means! All you did was store a *different* value in `Val`.

Imagine you have a scrap of paper on which you have written "Val" at the top (just to give it a name).  You then write "34" on it.  How many values do you have?  How many scraps of paper?

Now you cross out (or white-out) the "34" and write "38".  *Now* how many values do you have?  How many scraps of paper?

With *reference types* the analogy can work as well, but the "value" on the paper is a *reference* to a different scrap of paper.  If you change the value on the paper, the other scrap does not magically disappear.  It's the job of the cleaning crew (garbage collector) to look at all the scraps of paper lying around, see if any other scrap of paper is referencing it, and throw it away if there are no references.